# What is the correct way to parse the list items using Map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the below error during props parsing:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

in props `props.doubleArray`. However, when I print it, it shows me a double array in the console. What is the correct way to use map?

```
class Menu extends Component {

render() {
return (
<div className="menu__row">
            <ListItems
              doubleArray={[
                [
                  "New & Featured",
                  "Shop All New Arrivals",
                  "SNKRS Launch Calendar",
                  "Best of Air Max",
                  "Member Access",
                ],
                [
                  "New & Featured",
                  "Shop All New Arrivals",
                  "SNKRS Launch Calendar",
                  "Best of Air Max",
                  "Member Access",
                ],
                [
                  "New & Featured",
                  "Shop All New Arrivals",
                  "SNKRS Launch Calendar",
                  "Best of Air Max",
                  "Member Access",
                ],
                [
                  "New & Featured",
                  "Shop All New Arrivals",
                  "SNKRS Launch Calendar",
                  "Best of Air Max",
                  "Member Access",
                ],
              ]}
            />
            <ListItems />
          </div>

);
}
}

function ListItems(props) {
  return (
<div className="listItems">
  {props.doubleArray.map((array) => (
    <ul className="listItems__column" key={array.id} value={array}>
      <li className="listItems__title"> {array[0]}</li>
      {array.map((item, index) =>
        index > 0 ? (
          <li className="listItems__text" key={item.id} value={item}>
            {item}
          </li>
        ) : null
      )}
    </ul>
  ))}
</div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<div className="listItems">
  {props.doubleArray && props.doubleArray.map((array) => (
    <ul className="listItems__column" key={array.id} value={array}>
      <li className="listItems__title"> {array[0]}</li>
      {array.map((item, index) =>
        index > 0 ? (
          <li className="listItems__text" key={item.id} value={item}>
            {item}
          </li>
        ) : null
      )}
    </ul>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, my comment got removed here. && first validates and looks if the list exist and parse the items. Map exists only on the list of items i.e array of elements. Hope this answers your query.